# How to style date generated by GET request and received in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

```
I am trying to style the data which I am receiving from a GET request. The api is returning JSON format but I am not sure how to get started with the styling. My code looks like this: **Index.html file:**
    

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.9.6/dist/tailwind.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="h-screen w-screen bg-gray-200 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
       <div class="w-1/2 bg-white shadow-2xl rounded">
        <div class="bg-gray-700 rounded-t p-4">
            <p class="text-white">
                <span class="font-bold">GET</span>
                Fixtures by date - Includes:
                <span>localTeam</span>
                <span>visitorTeam</span>
                <span>Events</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-gray-200 p-4">
            <p>Response of GET in JSON format</p>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="p-4">
            <pre id="content"></pre>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my script.js file

```
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let api_token = "my_api_token";
    let includes = "&include=localTeam,visitorTeam,events";
    let url = "https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/date/2019-02-02?api_token=" + api_token + includes;

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        let response = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(response.data);

        const content = document.getElementById('content');
        content.textContent = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, "  ");
    }

    request.send();
```

Essentially all my data will be in a table format with date of the event, the two football teams next to each other and the final result of the match. I am trying to style the output data, unfortunately there is no much information in the documentation and I am not sure from where to start. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use CSS to style the elements that you will have to convert from received JSON data.

Comment: `unfortunately there is no much information in the documentation` which documentation? Also it seems you are adding your data as text. Not html. You can create a div ( wrapper ) and loop over the array of data ( i assume it's an array of objects ) and add each item in a div ( row ) and  item data in div ( columns) and then use `flexbox` and CSS to style them